# Нужна ли запятая перед словом "бОльшую" в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Потенциал каждого составляет в среднем сумму(,) б**о**льшую, чем 4,5 млн рублей.

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Если бы было "превышающую 4,5 млн рублей", тогда нужно было бы. А в вашем случае, ИМХО, не нужно. Но я не уверен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потенциал каждого составляет в среднем сумму большую, чем 4,5 млн рублей.

Запятая не нужна: нет паузы, логическое ударение смещено на определение.

Comment: Забавно: вывод верен, а посылка не верна. При чем здесь паузы?! Да еще логическое ударение. *Потенциал каждого составляет в среднем сумму бОльшую* - здесь для объяснения отсутствия запятой нужно привлекать "паузы"?

Comment: А вот Розенталь тоже учитывал интонацию, то есть паузы и ударение: "При отсутствии предшествующего определения последующие одиночные определения обособляются или не обособляются в зависимости от степени их ИНТОНАЦИОННО-СМЫСЛОВОЙ близости с определяемым существительным. 
Вместо весёлой петербургской жизни, ожидала меня скука в стороне глухой и отдалённой (П.); Под этой толстой серой шинелью билось сердце страстное и благородное (Л.);  Он стал рассказывать о детских своих днях словами крепкими и тяжёлыми.

Answer (score 0):

Так вообще нельзя сказать. Надо переставить местами слова, тогда всё с запятыми станет ясно.

> Потенциал каждого составляет в среднем большую чем 4,5 млн рублей сумму.

Comment: Ваш вариант гораздо хуже ))

Comment: А по-моему, он гораздо лучше!))))))

Comment: Вопрос о пунктуации стоит, а не о редактировании.

Comment: Как можно обсуждать вообще неправильное предложение?